# Android - How to create Right-to-Left Horizontal-ListView?

Tags: android, listview, horizontal-scrolling

Is there a practical way (in general) to create a right-to-left Horizontal-ListView in Android?

I already searched about it and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038129/how-to-assign-horizontal-scroll-right-to-left-in-listview-in-android) but its doesn't seem generally practical!

Comment: In my case I use HorizontalScrollView with 1 linear layout inside. And then, I populate the linearlayout programatically something like:

linearlayout1.addView(listviewitem); //Note listviewitem is any kind of view.

Comment: please check this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728837/recyclerview-grow-element-from-right-to-left/46315909#46315909)

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905575/4797289

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RecyclerView helped me out (instead of horizontal-list-view) {thanX to @user2641570}.

accordding to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#LinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean)):

> public LinearLayoutManager (Context context, int orientation, boolean
>   reverseLayout)
>
> Parameters context    Current context, will be used to access resources.
>
> orientation   Layout orientation. Should be HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL.
>
> **reverseLayout   When set to true, layouts from end to start.**

so I just declare LinearLayoutManager as follows:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
```

and everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview) is a post explaining how to use it for an horizontal list view.

Edit:

Here is a sample from the linked post.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

To use RecyclerView you should import the corresponding support library.

```
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0
```

Comment: as I searched about RecycleView in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727354/linearlayoutmanager-setreverselayout-true-but-items-stack-from-bottom, it is possible to make it Horizontal & RTL, but my minSdk is 11. is RecycleView OK with it?

Comment: I have not tried this but -v7 in the artificat id means that it should be compatible with all android version greater than 7 so it should work.